# JavaFX Grid lines styling

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-2

Is there a way to style the grid lines of a gridpane in JavaFx? I could only see the option to make it visible or hidden.

```
-fx-grid-lines-visible: true;
```

Even if we can set a background for each cell that would fill the entire cell just like in the following diagram, that would be great.

Is there really an option to do this either by CSS or by Java coding?

I added hgap and vgap to achieve this.

```
-fx-vgap: 10;
-fx-hgap: 10;
```

But it looks like this:-

[image: grid lines made visible with hgap and vgap]

I need to remove the intersecting lines as circled above. The required one would be like this:-

[image]

Comment: This is a debugging feature, see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#gridLinesVisibleProperty). If the children are all regions that completely fill the space, you could simply set the border on the children...